# Retrieveing GitHub user ID by OAuth2 token with Spring Social

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, github-api

Say I have completed an OAuth2 login and have an auth token.

I'm trying to get the user's name using that token. This is what I'm doing:

```
final GitHub gitHub = connectionFactory.createConnection(new AccessGrant(authToken)).getApi();
final String userId = gitHub.userOperations().getProfileId();
```

This is what I get, at `gitHub.userOperations().getProfileId()`:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:537)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:493)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:222)
org.springframework.social.github.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:50)
org.springframework.social.github.connect.GitHubAdapter.setConnectionValues(GitHubAdapter.java:43)
org.springframework.social.github.connect.GitHubAdapter.setConnectionValues(GitHubAdapter.java:30)
org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.setValues(AbstractConnection.java:172)
org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.initKey(AbstractConnection.java:135)
org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2Connection.<init>(OAuth2Connection.java:73)
org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:91)
net.librarian.app.service.impl.OAuth2Service.getAuthenticatedUserName(OAuth2Service.java:36)
```

So does anyone know if I've misunderstood the API somewhere ? To my understanding if I have the auth token (with the `user` scope) I should be able to get the user info ?

Thanks,

---

To answer the comment. This `curl -i https://api.github.com/user?access_token=TOKEN`, gets me:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Wed, 25 Dec 2013 13:41:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Status: 401 Unauthorized
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.beta
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1387982502
Content-Length: 92
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-        RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interva
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-GitHub-Request-Id: BCFEC363:32CA:5A1392E:52BAE095

{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "http://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I made the `curl` request no more than a minute (actually about 10 secs) after I requested a "fresh" token.

Comment: Can you verify that the token is valid by making the API call manually, using curl? E.g. 

$ curl -v https://api.github.com/user?access_token=TOKEN

Comment: @IvanZuzak Thanks for the help. I updated the question to answer your comment.

Comment: Hm, strange. Did you create a token using the authorizations API (http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization) or your settings (https://github.com/settings/applications)? Are you perhaps using a 2FA OTP token instead of an OAuth token?

Comment: @IvanZuzak Using the authorizations API. I use Spring Social to build a URL for the request `final OAuth2Operations operations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();` and `operations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.IMPLICIT_GRANT, params)`. The `params` var contains `user` and `public_repo` scopes.

Comment: @IvanZuzak Also the connection factory is initialized in the spring context using my app client and secret tokens.

Comment: Sorry, I know basically nothing about Spring Social. :) Do you see that token you created in your settings here: https://github.com/settings/applications ? Can you try creating a personal token manually (via that settings page) and using that to test you program (to see if you still get a 401)? Also, let's continue this over at support@github.com so that this doesn't turn into a support thread :)